# Не работает маршрутизация PHP MVC

Tags: php, mvc, router, роутинг

https://github.com/xRomax/WorkLeader
У меня есть шаблон admin.php который подключает стили, скрипты. Есть для каждой страницы свой php файл с вёрсткой, возьмём main.php. Если просто прописать http://WorkLeader/admin всё работает, загружается шаблон admin.php и в него в качестве контенте загружается main.php, но если в конец добавить слеш будет http://WorkLeader/admin**/** и шаблон не загружается, то есть то есть, сами теги показываются, но файлы со стилями, скриптами не подключаются. Так же само не работает если попробовать перейти на страницу http://WorkLeader/admin/login, сам файл login.php загружается, но стили и скрипты не работают, а если в роуте прописать в маршрутах просто login, то всё работает, но опять же, если в конце добавить слеш, опять то же самое.

Comment: Заметил в консоли, что если перейти просто по ссылке 
http://WorkLeader/admin
URL запрос будет:http://workleader/public/styles/materialize.css
а если по http://WorkLeader/admin**/**
URL запрос почему то криво срабатывает :http://workleader/admin/public/styles/materialize.css

Answer (score -1):

`<script src="public/scripts/jquery.js"></script>` ничего не работало

`<script src="/public/scripts/jquery.js"></script>` всё заработало